# Convert JSON to string or hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, string, hash

I have tried:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
require 'uri'

url = "http://xyz.com"
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
buffer = resp.body
result = JSON.parse(buffer)
#result.to_hash
    #pp result
puts result
```

And got the output as:

```
{"id"=>"ABC", "account_id"=>"123", "first_name"=> "PEUS" }
```

in JSON format but I only need the value of `id` to be printed as `ABC`.

Answer (score 11):

Your incoming string in JSON would look like:

```
{"id":"ABC","account_id":"123","first_name":"PEUS"}
```

After parsing with JSON it's the hash:

```
{"id"=>"ABC", "account_id"=>"123", "first_name"=> "PEUS" }
```

So, I'd use:

```
hash = {"id"=>"ABC", "account_id"=>"123", "first_name"=> "PEUS" }
hash['id'] # => "ABC"
```

Here's a more compact version:

```
require 'json'

json = '{"id":"ABC","account_id":"123","first_name":"PEUS"}'
hash = JSON[json]
hash['id'] # => "ABC"
```

Note I'm using `JSON[json]`. The JSON `[]` class method is smart enough to sense what the parameter being passed in is. If it's a string it'll parse the string. If it's an Array or Hash it'll serialize it. I find that handy because it allows me to write `JSON[...]` instead of having to remember whether I'm parsing or using `to_json` or something. Using it is an example of [the first virtue of programmers](http://threevirtues.com).

Comment: Can we have automated process rather than picking the JSON manually and mapping it as hash.I would not like to do the same manually for thousands of record.

Comment: That's why we write code to automate tasks. You haven't described your additional needs at all so I can't help you much. I'd recommend learning how to get directory entries, and open and read files.

Comment: Suppose if I am hitting the URL with multiple values then i that case I can;t hard code  it

Comment: I am able to get the value as 
id:ABC
account_id:123
first_name:PEUS



I CHANGED THE CODE AS :
hash = JSON[buffer]
hash[0].each do |key,value|
        puts "#{key}:#{value}"
end

BUT STILL I NEED ONLY VALUE FOR ID

Comment: I can't help you. You're not giving a real URL, nor is your sample data matching what your code in the comment shows, which, BTW, is almost unreadable because you stuck it in your comment, not appending it to your answer. _DOES_ your JSON look like what I show in my answer? Is it a single hash?